# Как получить доступ из базового класса к методам и данным производного?

Tags: c++

Есть примитивные классы:

```
class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() { }
};

template <typename T>
class D : public B {
public:
    T _valD;
    D(T x) { _valD = x; };
};
```

Далее:

```
B* _bp = nullptr;
// Какой то код...
_bp = new D<double>(3.24);
_bp = reinterpret_cast<D<double>*>(_bp);
```

Теперь хотелось бы получить доступ через указатель _bp к свойству D._valD. Что-то типа _bp->_valD. В книгах написано, что указателю базового класса можно присвоить адрес производного (так называемый полиморфизм), но при этом через указатель на базовый класс получить доступ к методам производного нельзя, за исключением виртуальных методов. Хотя существует оговорка: нужно выполнить приведение указателя базового класса к производному.
Но вот как сделать это приведение и получить доступ через указатель базового класса к обычным методам и свойствам производного понять не могу. Дайте пожалуйста ответ: такое в принципе возможно в С++? И если возможно, то как доработать вышеуказанный код?

P.S. Пробовал dynamic_cast. Безуспешно. Если смотреть на _bp через отладчик, то он содержит в себе значение _valD, но как до него добраться, непонятно.

Comment: Через указатель `_bp` доступ к полям объекта дочернего класса получить нельзя. С++ является языком со ститической типизацией. Соответственно для обращения к полям дочернего класса нужен указатель (или ссылка) на объект соотв. дочернего класса. `D<double> * p_d{static_cast<D<double> *>(_bp)}; p_d->_valD = 2.0;`

Comment: Печально. Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Мне бы еще подошел std::variant, но для доступа к текущему хранимому значению методу get нужно жестко "вручную" задать либо тип, либо индекс. Какая то патовая ситуация. С одной стороны в языке есть всякие tamplate<typename T>, с другой жесткая типизация. В итоге приходится плодить избыточный код.

Comment: Типизация в языке не жесткая. всякие tamplate<typename T> позволяют реализовать полиморфизм времени компиляции, а вы с классом с виртуальными методами делаете полиморфизм времени выполнения. Никакого избыточного кода плодить не приходится.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что `_bp = reinterpret_cast<D<double>*>(_bp);` ничего не делает?

Comment: В принципе да, если cast вообще убрать, то тоже работает. Даже если сделать void*_bp.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить доступ к членам класса "D", нужно использовать dynamic_cast, но нужно удостовериться, что класс B имеет хотяб 1 виртуальный метод

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() { }
    // Добавим виртуальную функцию, чтобы dynamic_cast работал
    virtual void dummy() {}
};

template <typename T>
class D : public B {
public:
    T _valD;
    D(T x) { _valD = x; };
};

int main() {
    B* _bp = nullptr;

    // Присваиваем указатель на объект D<double>
    _bp = new D<double>(3.24);

    // Приводим указатель к D<double>* с помощью dynamic_cast
    if (auto* d_ptr = dynamic_cast<D<double>*>(_bp)) {
        // Теперь можем получить доступ к _valD
        std::cout << d_ptr->_valD << std::endl;
    }

    // Не забудем освободить выделенную память
    delete _bp;

    return 0;
}
```

Что-то вроде такого

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно. В Вашем варианте создается новый d_ptr, который живет только в рамках оператора if, и который при рождении является указателем на D. Так я уже делал. Но вся соль в том, чтобы получить доступ через ранее созданный указатель _bp. Дело в том, что пример упрощен до варианта _bp = new D<double>(3.24);. Но возможен вариант _bp = new D<int>(3); или _bp = new D<std::strung>("test"); и т.п. Т.е. _bp присваивается какой то из вариантов, заранее неизвестный, и затем последующий код работает через _bp с тем, что получил _bp.

Answer (score -1):

Оказалось был в шаге от решения. Достаточно добавить:

```
auto value = (*(D<double>*)_bp)._valD;
```

В итоге, переменная value получает и значение, и ей назначается тип от D._valD (в данном случае double).

Дальше можно проделать следующее:

```
delete _bp;
_bp = new D<int>(3);
auto value2 = (*(D<int>*)_bp)._valD;
```

Теперь переменная value2 получит значение и тип int.

Comment: Лучше `static_cast`, а не сишный каст. Здесь эффект тот же, но об сишный каст можно отстрелить ногу: если наследование потом убрать, а каст оставить, он втихую станет работать неправильно (или просто если сразу указать не потомка, а какой-то несвязанный класс). Ну и можно случайно снять константность, и т.п.

Comment: На счет static_cast согласен. Использовал reinterpret_cast от безысходности, когда "бился головой об стену", в качестве наиболее сильного средства от головной боли. По мне так любой cast не есть хорошо. Стараюсь избегать. Но в данном случае cast будет надежно заперт в рамках одной несложной и легко отслеживаемой функции. Есть решение и без cast, но менее красивое. Когда наткнулся на эту "проблему", зацепило что то. В документации написано, что приведение возможно, но как - не написано.